# If x enter data, else retrieve data. PHP & SQL

Tags: php, sql, forms, if-statement

Here is my code, I have been attempting to find a way to do this.

The point of the code is to do this:

Check database, see if field is filled, if not post form. Once form is filled, submit data to database, then reload page to go to step 2.

Else if field is full show data in database, and bypass the first part.

```
    <?php
  require_once('connectvars.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html 

     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>PDI Non-Conforming Materials Report</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/view.css" />
</head>
<body>
</body> 
</html>
<?php

echo '<form id="all">';
echo '<fieldset>';
echo '<div id="box4-1">';
// We know both $ncmrsr AND $ncmrsc are blank
$row['ncmrsr'] = trim($row['ncmrsr']);
$row['ncmrsc'] = trim($row['ncmrsc']);
if (empty($row['ncmrsr']) && empty($row['ncmrsc'])) {
     // code to add comment would go here.
        echo '<div id="ncmrsr"><span class="b">NCMR Supplier Response:<br /></span><textarea name="ncmrsr" rows="6" cols="85">"N/A"</textarea></div><br />';
        echo '<br />';
        echo '<div id="ncmrsc"><span class="b">NCMR Supplier Comment:<br /></span><textarea name="ncmrsr" rows="6" cols="85" ></textarea></div><br />';
        }



else {
// echo the two fields
                if (!empty($row['ncmrsr'])) {
                    echo '<div id="ncmrsr"><span class="b">NCMR Supplier Response:<br /></span>' . $row['ncmrsr'] . '</div>';}
                if (!empty($row['ncmrsc'])) {
                    echo '<div id="ncmrsc"><span class="b">NCMR Supplier Comment:<br /></span>' . $row['ncmrsc'] . '</div>';}
                    echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</fieldset>';
echo '</form>';

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so first of all you end your html tag before you echo any dynamic fields. Second you always generate the form no matter what the data says. Third you echo `<tr>` and `<td>` tags without a containing table. Fourth you only end the form and div tags if there is no data in the $row variable. So there is a lot going on thats wrong.

```
<?php
  require_once('connectvars.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html 

     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>PDI Non-Conforming Materials Report</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/view.css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php



// We know both $ncmrsr AND $ncmrsc are blank
$row['ncmrsr'] = trim($row['ncmrsr']);
$row['ncmrsc'] = trim($row['ncmrsc']);
if (empty($row['ncmrsr']) && empty($row['ncmrsc'])) {
     // code to add comment would go here.
        echo '<form id="all" method="post" action="pagetosaveformtoDB.php">';
        echo '<fieldset>';
        echo '<div id="box4-1">';
        echo '<div id="ncmrsr"><span class="b">NCMR Supplier Response:<br /></span><textarea name="ncmrsr" rows="6" cols="85">"N/A"</textarea></div><br />';
        echo '<div id="ncmrsc"><span class="b">NCMR Supplier Comment:<br /></span><textarea name="ncmrsr" rows="6" cols="85" ></textarea></div><br />
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />';
        echo '</div></fieldset></form>';
        }

else {
// echo the two fields
       echo '<div id="box4-1">';
       if (!empty($row['ncmrsr'])) {
          echo '<div id="ncmrsr"><span class="b">NCMR Supplier Response:<br /></span>' . $row['ncmrsr'] . '</div>';}
       if (!empty($row['ncmrsc'])) {
          echo '<div id="ncmrsc"><span class="b">NCMR Supplier Comment:<br /></span>' . $row['ncmrsc'] . '</div>';}
           echo '</div>';

}
?>
</body> 
</html>
```

Also I am not sure what connectvars is doing and if thats where the $row variable is coming from so I would def more information if that doesnt fix it.

Comment: Actually I don't always post the form.  If the fields aren't empty I go to the second aspect of it. I know it does because I've make it work...

Second, the TR and TD are irrelivant, it is random bits of information that won't be used and fixed later.

thirdly if you want a link here it is: 

http://kaboomlabs.com/PDI/@dm!n/viewncmr.php?id=1
http://kaboomlabs.com/PDI/@dm!n/viewncmr.php?id=2

Comment: ok well then if there is nothing to submit then you dont need a form. I mean what you are doign may work but all you are coding is very crappy code.

Comment: you DONT NEED IT.. a form is for submitting data you can programically not code it in.

Comment: There is data to submit...  http://kaboomlabs.com/PDI/test.php

There is the form you are complaining about that doesn't exist in the text above... it exists, it works, and it requires the ability to submit. 

Please help or don't.  Instead of using HTML I am using PHP, if you don't know how to incorporate a form using PHP as a wrapper please don't waste my time and yours.  

I know this works, I have it up and running. 

What I need to know is how to make it work to submit the data to a field in a database, that is all.

Comment: if you looked at my answer I added an input of type submit. What that does is takes the data in the form and sends it to a page that page could be the current page or a new page. Now for getting the data into the database, I dont know what connnection you are using that is why I was asking about the connectvars because that is most likey shows what you are using. So after you answer that question I would be able to tell you how to put the data in the table.