# My code is not posting, although to me everything looks correct

Tags: php, sql, post

Here is my code, basically its written so that all you need to do is hit submit.  I am getting an error though:

The data isn't posting.  I can't understand why. I am not a master coder by any stretch of the imagination, but I think I have everything correct.  Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks

```
<?php

require_once('connectvars.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html 

     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>PDI Non-Conforming Materials Report</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/postie.css" />

</head>

<body>
<div id="logo">
    <img src="images/PDI_Logo_2.1.gif" alt="PDI Logo" />
</div>

<div id="title">
    <h3 id="NCMR2">Non-Conforming Materials Report (NCMR)</h3>
</div>

<?php

//Post Data
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $ab = $_POST['ab'];
    $date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['date']));
    $part = $_POST['part'];
    $rev = $_POST['rev'];
    $partdesc = $_POST['partdesc'];
    $ncmrqty = $_POST['ncmrqty'];
    $comp = $_POST['comp'];
    $ncmrid = $_POST['ncmrid'];
    $rma = $_POST['rma'];
    $jno = $_POST['jno'];
    $in = $_POST['in'];
    $tp = $_POST['tp'];
    $cof = $_POST['cof'];
    $fab1= $_POST['fab1'];
    $fab2= $_POST['fab2'];
    $fab3= $_POST['fab3'];
    $non= $_POST['non'];
    $dis= $_POST['dis'];
    $comm= $_POST['comm'];
    $caad= $_POST['caad'];
    $po= $_POST['po'];
    $pod = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['pod']));
    $dri = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['dri']));
    $output_form = 'no';

    if (empty($ab) || empty($date) || empty($part) || empty($partdesc) || empty($ncmrid) || empty($non) || empty($dis) || empty($po) || empty($pod) || empty($dri)) {

    // We know at least one of the input fields is blank 
    echo 'Please fill out all of the required NCMR information.<br />';
    $output_form = 'yes';
        }
    }
  else {
    $output_form = 'yes';
    }
//Access the Database
    if (!empty($ab) && !empty($date) && !empty($pod)) {
        $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
        or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

    $query = "INSERT INTO ncmr (ab, date, part, rev, partdesc, ncmrqty, comp, ncmrid, rma, jno, in, tp, cof, fab1, fab2, fab3, non, dis, comm, caad, po, pod, dri)

    VALUES ('$ab', '$date', '$part', '$rev', '$partdesc', '$ncmrqty', '$comp', '$ncmrid', '$rma', '$jno', '$in', '$tp', '$cof', '$fab1', '$fab2', '$fab3', '$non', '$dis', '$comm', '$caad', '$po', '$pod', '$dri')";

    mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
      or die ('Data not inserted.');

      // Confirm success with the user
      echo '<tr><td class="thank">';
      echo '<p>Thank you for adding the NCRM, the correct person will be informed.</p>';
      echo '<p><a href="post.php">&lt;&lt; Back to the form</a></p>';
      echo '</td></tr>';

    mysqli_close($dbc);
  }
  if ($output_form == 'yes') {
        echo '<form method="post">';
            echo '<fieldset>';
        //Part, Rev, Part Description, NCMR Qty
            echo '<div id="box1">';
                echo '<div id="ab"><span class="b">Added By:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="ab" value="" /></div>';
                echo '<div id="date"><span class="b">Date Filed:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="date" value="" /></div>';
                echo '<div id="part"><span class="b">Part Number:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="part" value="" /></div>';
                echo '<div id="rev"><span class="b">Part Revision:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="rev" value="" /></div>';
                echo '<div id="partdesc"><span class="b">Part Description:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea name="partdesc" rows="3" cols="22" ></textarea></div>';
                echo '<div id="ncmrqty"><span class="b">NCMR Qty:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="ncmrqty" value="" /></div>';
            echo '</div>';

//Inventory On Hand, Inventory Check, Supplier Name, Supplier Number, Manufacturer Part Number, Manufactuer Serial Number and NCMR ID
            echo '<div id="box2">';
                echo'<div id="comp">';
                    echo '<span class="b">Company:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>';
                    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
$mysqli->select_db('comp');

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM comp"); 
$i = 0;

echo "<SELECT name='comp'>\n";

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 if ($i == 3) echo '<option value="lines">-----</option>';

 echo "<option value='{$row['user_id']}'>{$row['name']}</option>\n";

 $i++;
}

echo "</select>\n";

                echo '</div>';

                echo '<div id="ncmrid"><span class="b">Customer NCMR ID:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="ncmrid" value="" /></div>';
                echo '<div id="rma"><span class="b">Internal RMA #:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="rma" value="" /></div>';
                echo '<div id="jno"><span class="b">Job #:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="jno" value="" /></div>';
            echo '</div>';

//Type of Failure and Class of Failure
            echo '<div id="box3">';
                echo '<h2>Failure Due To</h2>';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="ih" value="0" /><br />';
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="ih" value="1" /> In House<br />';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="tp" value="0" /><br />';
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="tp" value="1" /> Third Party<br />';
                echo'<div id="cof">';
                    echo '<span class="b">Class of Failure:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><br />';
                    echo '<select name="cof">';
                    echo '<option value="none">----None----</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Materials">Materials</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Fabrication">Fabrication</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Drawing">Drawing</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Assembly">Assembly</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Testing">Testing</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Electrical">Electrical</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Programming">Programming</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Machining">Machining</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Inspection">Inspection</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Purchasing">Purchasing</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Administrator">Administrator</option>';
                    echo '</select>';
                echo '</div>';

            echo '</div>';

//Fabricators
            echo '<div id="box4">';
                echo '<h2>Fabricators</h2>';
                            echo'<div id="fab1">';
                    echo '<select name="fab1">';
                    echo '<option value="none">===None===</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Andy Kahl">Andy Kahl</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Anthony Ayoub">Anthony Ayoub</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Bob Payne">Bob Payne</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Butch Laplante">Butch Laplante</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Daryl Flynn">Daryl Flynn</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Derrick Clark">Derrick Clark</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Dolores Drinkwater">Dolores Drinkwater</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Errol Flynn">Errol Flynn</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Gary Capella">Gary Capella</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Gelia Moril">Gelia Moril</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Gregg Tansino">Gregg Tansino</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Kevin Sullivan">Kevin Sullivan</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Kurt Flynn">Kurt Flynn</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Matt Ross">Matt Ross</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Mike Sullivan">Mike Sullivan</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Patrick Walsh">Patrick Walsh</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Ralph Block">Ralph Block</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Rick Guay">Rick Guay</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Scott Hamel">Scott Hamel</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Scott King">Scott King</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Scott Pazerbiak">Scott Pazerbiak</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Scott Zizza">Scott Zizza</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Shaun Tardiff">Shaun Tardiff</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Sherry Ryan">Sherry Ryan</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Terry Wilkins">Terry Wilkins</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Wade Page">Wade Page</option>';
                    echo '</select>';
                echo '</div>';

                    echo'<div id="fab2">';
                    echo '<select name="fab2">';
                    echo '<option value="none">===None===</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Andy Kahl">Andy Kahl</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Anthony Ayoub">Anthony Ayoub</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Bob Payne">Bob Payne</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Butch Laplante">Butch Laplante</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Daryl Flynn">Daryl Flynn</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Derrick Clark">Derrick Clark</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Dolores Drinkwater">Dolores Drinkwater</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Errol Flynn">Errol Flynn</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Gary Capella">Gary Capella</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Gelia Moril">Gelia Moril</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Gregg Tansino">Gregg Tansino</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Kevin Sullivan">Kevin Sullivan</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Kurt Flynn">Kurt Flynn</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Matt Ross">Matt Ross</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Mike Sullivan">Mike Sullivan</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Patrick Walsh">Patrick Walsh</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Ralph Block">Ralph Block</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Rick Guay">Rick Guay</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Scott Hamel">Scott Hamel</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Scott King">Scott King</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Scott Pazerbiak">Scott Pazerbiak</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Scott Zizza">Scott Zizza</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Shaun Tardiff">Shaun Tardiff</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Sherry Ryan">Sherry Ryan</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Terry Wilkins">Terry Wilkins</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Wade Page">Wade Page</option>';
                    echo '</select>';
                echo '</div>';

                            echo'<div id="fab3">';
                    echo '<select name="fab3">';
                    echo '<option value="none">===None===</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Andy Kahl">Andy Kahl</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Anthony Ayoub">Anthony Ayoub</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Bob Payne">Bob Payne</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Butch Laplante">Butch Laplante</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Daryl Flynn">Daryl Flynn</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Derrick Clark">Derrick Clark</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Dolores Drinkwater">Dolores Drinkwater</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Errol Flynn">Errol Flynn</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Gary Capella">Gary Capella</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Gelia Moril">Gelia Moril</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Gregg Tansino">Gregg Tansino</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Kevin Sullivan">Kevin Sullivan</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Kurt Flynn">Kurt Flynn</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Matt Ross">Matt Ross</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Mike Sullivan">Mike Sullivan</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Patrick Walsh">Patrick Walsh</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Ralph Block">Ralph Block</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Rick Guay">Rick Guay</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Scott Hamel">Scott Hamel</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Scott King">Scott King</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Scott Pazerbiak">Scott Pazerbiak</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Scott Zizza">Scott Zizza</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Shaun Tardiff">Shaun Tardiff</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Sherry Ryan">Sherry Ryan</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Terry Wilkins">Terry Wilkins</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Wade Page">Wade Page</option>';
                    echo '</select>';
                echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';

             //Nonconformity, Disposition, Comments and Comments & Additional Details
            echo '<div id="box5">';
                    echo '<div id="non"><span class="b">Nonconformity:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><br /><textarea name="non" rows="3" cols="110" ></textarea><br /></div>';
                    echo '<div id="dis"><span class="b">Disposition:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><br /><textarea name="dis" rows="3" cols="110" ></textarea></div>';
                    echo '<div id="comm"><span class="b">Comments:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><br /><textarea name="comm" rows="3" cols="110" ></textarea></div>';
                    echo '<div id="caad"><span class="b">Comments and/or Additional Details:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><br /><textarea name="caad" rows="3" cols="110" ></textarea></div>';
            //PO, PO Date, and Date Recieved
            echo '<div id="podr">';
                    echo '<div id="po"><span class="b">PO:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="po"  size="7" value="" /></div>';
                    echo '<div id="pod"><span class="b">PO Date:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="pod"  size="7" value="" /></div>';
                    echo '<div id="dri"><span class="b">Date Received:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="dri"  size="7" value=""';
            echo '</div>';
                    echo '<div id="button"><input type="submit" value="Submit NCMR" name="submit" /></div>';
            echo '</div>';



    echo '</fieldset>';
echo '</form>';
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help you if you make an example that is as small as possible, but still has the same problem. This big piece of code makes it harder to see the problemen. Also for you own debugging: just strip away all the other html, choices etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [If x enter data, else retrieve data. PHP & SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142170/if-x-enter-data-else-retrieve-data-php-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your form doesn't have an `ACTION` set to it - that is what decides where to send the data.

So, change the line:

```
 echo '<form method="post">';
```

To something like:

```
 echo '<form method="post" action="http://url.to/your_file.php">';
```

Comment: @ Tudor Did it, and still not working. @RaghavBhushan it was working before without the need for the action, and it worked fine.

Comment: I've solved it, mostly.  It posts without issue, except now it's not posting the data from the drop-down menus...

Comment: It turned out it was on the database end, a field was missmarked... the code was correct, mostly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You have only given *values* to each option but no *names*, which are the basic requirements for a post value to be identified.

Comment: What do you mean? No names? Everything there has a "name" attached to it... @Raghav No it didn't.

Comment: are you sure that a mysql connection is perfectly established./

Answer (score 0):

I can save you a lot of time by giving you this

```
<?
foreach ($_POST as $k=>$v) $$k=$v;
?>
```

All That code above where your moving your $_POST variables to your $normal scope can be done with my tiny peice of code above. ALSO You have serious errors with your Form

Comment: Your form tag is missing arguments